# insert order of array into database

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, zend-framework

I created a form using javascript and php. I have used a textbox like

```
 <input type="textbox" name="listid" value="" />
```

I will get an array like 4,6,12,9 etc from $_POST['listid']; I can insert this values into database using serialize and retreive it by unserialize. But what I need to do is, insert 1 for listid=4, 2 for listid=6, 3 for listid=12 and 4 for listid=9. I have used

```
$count=0;

 foreach($_POST['listid]' as $id)
        {

            $count++;
    $db->update('lists',array('order'=>$count),'id ='.$db->quote($id));

        }
```

But it is not working. Only updating first value(listid=4)

What I need to do? Anyone please help??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not receive an array from $_POST['listid], you will get a string. First split that string into an array, then implement the logic.

```
$arrListId = split(',', $_POST['listid]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$count=0;
 foreach($_POST['listid'] as $id)
        {

            $count++;
    $db->update('lists',array('order'=>$count),'id ='.$db->quote($id));

        }

?>
```

**Remove $count=0; out of the for loop**

Comment: Weird, can you add `echo $id.'-'.$count;` in the for loop to see whether it runs more than one time and the count is incrementing.

Comment: I have added like $db->update('lists',array('order'=>$id),'id ='.$db->quote($id));(changed order=>$count into order=>$id) then the database is inserting like 4,6,12,9. not one value.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$count=0;
foreach($_POST['listid]' as $id)
{   
    $count++;
    $data   =   array('order'=>$count);
    $db->update('lists',$data,$this->_db->quoteInto('id = ?',$id));
}
```

i hope this may work